# PretrainedConfig with non-serializable JSON attribute

Tags: json, python-3.x, pytorch

I am building a custom model that consist of multiple pre-trained models (e.g. BERT). I want to have a global `PretrainedConfig` that control these group of pre-trained models.

Examples such as:

```
from transformers import PretrainedConfig, BertConfig, GPT2Config
class GlobalConfig(PretrainedConfig):
    def __init__(self, model_a_cfg=None, model_b_cfg=None, *inputs, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.model_a_cfg = model_a_cfg
        self.model_b_cfg = model_b_cfg

class Config1(BertConfig):
    def __init__(self, *inputs, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

class Config2(GPT2Config):
    def __init__(self, *inputs, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
```

This results in:

```
bert_config = Config1()
gpt_config = Config2()
GlobalConfig(bert_config, gpt_config)

# TypeError: Object of type Config1 is not JSON serializable
```

I would expect the `Global_Config` work out like this

```
from transformers import BertModel, GPT2Model

class GlobalModel(PreTrainedModel):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.config = config
        self.model_a = BertModel(config.model_a_cfg)
        self.model_b = GPT2Model(config.model_b_cfg)

config = GlobalConfig(bert_config, gpt_config)
global_model = GlobalModel(config)
```

What would be the best way to address this problem?